# Can Swagger/other API documentation/tool provide information if a rest end point is consuming external rest endpoints

Tags: rest, web-services, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, api-doc

Recently had to do analysis over the rest endpoints in a system(in microservices architecture) which are internally consuming external rest end endpoints. These endpoints belong to either other microservices or to third party web services.

Just curious to know if Swagger can be customized to achieve this or is there any other tool which can help me in gathering or visualising this information.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [OpenAPI Spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) (previously known as the Swagger file) it doesn't look like it defines connected endpoints. Which makes sense, since it's purpose is to define an interface to an API, not it's underlying implementation. It does, however, provide a way to link to external documentation using the [External Documentation Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#externalDocumentationObject). This could link to documentation about what endpoints the given API uses.

If you want to get a real-time look at what endpoints your services are consuming take a look at [New Relics - Service Map](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/using-new-relic/service-maps/get-started/introduction-service-maps) and [Instana - Dependency Maps](https://www.instana.com/blog/automatic-application-flow-maps-services-endpoints/). I'm sure other APM tools do this too, but these are the two I know of. The downfall to these is they are not free.

One other way to do this is write a tool to parse your config files looking for all external dependencies. This, of course, would require standards and naming conventions in your services for identifying those endpoints.